# How to parse variables returned in browser script to Python code?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am runnning the following script in the browser

`webdriver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('bulk_item').length")`

and I want the number this script returns to be assigned to an `elem` variable that I can access.
Direct assignment doesn't work.
The error is on line :

```py
self.assertEqual(elem_before+1, elem_after, "UPLOAD FAILED")
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `return` statement.

```
webdriver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('bulk_item').length")
```